# Is there any plugin to show the results(.xls file) in pipeline job in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a requirement to show the xls file in the pipeline job of jenkins.Is there any plug-in which met my requirement.

Comment: How would you show the contents of an .xls file normally? For example, from the command line? If you can do that, you can run it in a Pipeline.

Comment: I dont know how to show the contents of an .xls file in normal job also.

Comment: Do you know how to show contents of an xml file in the tabular format in Jenkins.

Comment: Not offhand, aside from maybe using XSLT (but that's for XML, not for .XLS, as you originally asked; .XLSX does contain XML, but in a zip container). That's an unrelated question, so you'd have to check Google or ask on another Stack Exchange site — Super User might be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no public Jenkins plugin that shows the results of a .xls file.

As previously suggested on the [jenkinsci-users mailing list](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jenkinsci-users/nogvOsSiPWQ/tpxqX8dGAQAJ), you could perhaps convert the file to CSV first and use the [Plot plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/plot), depending on the type of data you have.